# can we use current version magento2 in production mode with full stack development work

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, ecommerce-tracking

I will need  make e-commerce site . I know  that magento is best e-commerce platform but   I have confusion that  magento2 is stable development for production.

I need make [website](https://www.wheresmypandit.com%3Cbr%3E) like

**Recruitments My site**

```
-product listing
-blog
-costume  functionality
-event management
-multi vendor
```

Comment: Yes, you can use Magento2.

Comment: but can we get all extension ? which is better currently magento 1.9 or  magento 2

Answer (score 0):

You use magento2. regarding extension all extension company have update their module with in 2-3 months you check most of company done thier jow because magento is fastest growing e commerce platform.

Comment: any best resources for magento2 development

Comment: best resource means you need developer ya any document regarding magento 2 ?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-2 here limit number  of extension.

Comment: or wocommerce is  better then magento2

Comment: best resource means.where  i can get best stable example for custome extension  development.template for magento 2 ect